# как отправлять теги на гитхаб

Tags: git, github

Я локально создал новый тег с ключом `-a`, после того, как я отправил внесенные изменения на github, то в списке тегов его там не появилось.
Как его добавить туда? Или когда там повится? Или моэет это другие теги?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Локально список тегов я вижу, через `git tag`

Comment: [2.6 Основы Git - Работа с метками](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить тэг:

```
git tag -a v1.4 -m 'my version 1.4'
```

Отправить тэг:

```
git push origin --tags
```